# Creating a red/yellow/green conditional format for cell based on percentage increase of other cell value

Tags: google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to use a conditional formatting in cells, using the Green/Amber/Red range based on a percentage increase in cell value from another target cell.

So far I've tried using a conditional format of applying red to B2 using conditional format `=$C2>=0.9`

I'm not sure this is working correctly for Red (alone). How can I apply my three conditional formats to the one cell, please?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the remaining two rules to the same cell:

[image]